# c# interface in inheritant class

Tags: c#, interface

```
    static Eleve[] eleves = new Eleve[6];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] notes;

        eleves[0] = new Faineant("Schtroumpf", "Faineant");
        eleves[1] = new Fourbe("Schtroumpf", "Fourbe");
        eleves[2] = new Bon("Schtroumpf", "Bon");
        eleves[3] = new Fayot("Schtroumpf", "Fayot");
        eleves[4] = new PasTresBon("Schtroumpf", "PasTrèsBon");
        eleves[5] = new PasTresBon("Schtroumpf", "PasTrèsBon 2");

        eleves[1].triche(); //Here is the problem ! not swag.
     }
```

*

```
class Personne
    {    public virtual void triche() {}
        public virtual void prepareLeCafe() { }
    }
```

*

```
abstract class Eleve : Personne ;
```

*

```
class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur
   { void ITricheur.triche()
    {
        min = 15;
        max = 15;
    }
}
```

*

```
public interface ITricheur
{
    void triche();
}
```

The method called when running "eleves[1].triche() ;" is the one in class Personne and not the one in class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur. Can someone explain us our error ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your array is declared as `Eleve[]`, so the methods will be called on `Eleve`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you missed out something in your code example. I just added the missing parts from compiler and it works.

The question would now be: Do you like to get into `Personne.triche()` or into `Tricheur.triche()`?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static Eleve[] eleves = new Eleve[6];

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        eleves[0] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "Faineant");
        eleves[1] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "Fourbe");
        eleves[2] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "Bon");
        eleves[3] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "Fayot");
        eleves[4] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "PasTrèsBon");
        eleves[5] = new Tricheur("Schtroumpf", "PasTrèsBon 2");

        var eleve = eleves[1];
        var tricheur = eleve as ITricheur;

        if (tricheur != null)
            tricheur.triche();

        eleve.triche();
    }
}

public interface ITricheur
{
    void triche();
}

internal abstract class Eleve : Personne
{ }

internal class Personne
{
    public virtual void prepareLeCafe()
    { }

    public virtual void triche()
    { }
}

internal class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur
{
    private int max;
    private int min;

    public Tricheur(string a, string b)
    {
    }

    void ITricheur.triche()
    {
        min = 15;
        max = 15;
    }
}
```

#### Update

So to get into `Tricheur.triche()` you should change your implementation that way:

```
internal class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur
{
    public Tricheur(string a, string b)
    {
    }

    void ITricheur.triche()
    {
        // If you remove this method, you'll get
        // always into the overriden method below.
    }

    public override void triche()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: We'd like to get into Tricheur.triche(), sorry we were'nt precise enough in our post

Answer (score 2):

In your case objects in `Eleve[]` must be of type `Tricheur` than it will take the implementation you want or all of your other classes (`Faineant`, `Fourbe`, ...) have also to implement the same implementation like `Tricheur` (but last is bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

**If `Fourbe` is a direct child of `Eleve`**

The array you created is of type `Eleve`.

```
tatic Eleve[] eleves = new Eleve[6];
```

`Eleve` extends `Personne` and `Personne` contains a method `triche`. That is why the `Personne.triche` is getting called.

The class `class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur` is not actually comes after `Eleve`. So, there is no point for its `triche` to get called.

**If `Fourbe` is a direct child of `Tricheur`**

You need to override `triche` this way,

```
class Tricheur : Eleve, ITricheur
{ 
    public void override ITricheur.triche()
    {
        min = 15;
        max = 15;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two methods:

```
public virtual void triche() {}
```

and

```
void ITricheur.triche()
```

are two *different* methods. The letter one being an [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) of `ITricheur.triche`.

In case you really want to create a virtual `triche` method in the ultimate ancestor, you have to *override* it in the descendant (regardless it's declared in the interface as well — the two will actually match), like this:

```
public override void triche() { … }
```

Comment: Effectively it works as we wish it would, but isn't there a "nicer" way to do it using the interface ?

Answer (score 0):

You have methods with same name at class and interface,  by default you call method from `Personne`(parent) class. If you need call method from `ITrecheur` you must call

`(eleves[1] as ITricheur).triche();`

Answer (score 0):

you issue is the following Tricheur inherits from Eleve so your debugger see the triche() as correct but at runtime will not do anything as virtual has no implentation and nothing will be executed
so you should do something like this

```
public class Personne { 

public virtual void triche() { } 

public virtual void prepareLeCafe() { } 
}

    public abstract class Eleve : Personne
    {
        public override void triche()
        {
            // here your code 
        }
    }
```